# The impact of adverse historical event on individual time preference

Tags: evolutionary-psychology, cross-cultural-psychology, time, preferences

I am a Development Economist, I recently get interested in **time preference** reading several insightful economic papers (Godoy 1998, Godoy 2001, Holden et al 1998, Holden 2013, Galor and Ozak 2015).

I am currently looking for more bibliography on **time preference** and especially on **the factors that can explain heterogeneity in time preference for individuals from a given population**. If anyone of you know any research paper on the factors explaining within population variation in time preference I will be happy to read your comments.

What I plan to do is to assess whether, within a given population, individuals whose ancestors faced adverse historical event (such as forced migration (i.e. forced village relocation) during colonial times, around 70 years ago) exhibit today higher levels of time preference compared to their peers not affected by such event. The channel would be that such behavior, due to forced migration that uprooted former generations, transmitted through *culture* from one generation to the other. 
In an agrarian economy, these differences in time preference would translate today in different investment behavior (such as decision to fallow land).

<sub>Godoy 1998 "The role of tenure security and private time preference in Neotropical Deforestation" Land Economics, Vol 74, No.2 May 1998 pp 162-170

Godoy 2001 "Tenure security, private time preference, and use of resources among lowland Bolivian Amerindians" Ecological Economics 38 (2001) 105-118

Holden et al 1998 "Poverty, market imperfections and time preferences: of relevance for environmental policy?" Environment and Development Economics 3 (1998) 105-130

Galor and Ozak 2015 "The Agricultural Origins of Time Preference" Working paper</sub>